# How to implement bluetooth pan profile in iphone

Tags: swift

I am having a iOS project which interacts with a bluetooth hardware device using bluetooth PAN profile. As i see, Apple supports bluetooth PAN profile. I tried to search for how to implement, but i have not find out the answer. Could any one help me, is it possible to implement PAN profile in iOS, or which iOS framework support? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

iPhone does not support PANU role APIs(to app developers), but supports NAP role in PAN. Third party devices can issue PANU connection to iPhone.